# windows metro app timer example

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

i am looking for timer in my window store app, but i got worried result

what i have done is something like this :

```
public ItemsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += ItemsPage_Loaded;
}

void ItemsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                    Updateloaction();

        }

DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        public void Updateloaction()
        {
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }
```

and call some method there

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            // do some changes every 10 seconds
        }
```

but my event

> timer_Tick

is not firing at all :( ?

why?

what i am trying to do is, when i start my app, i need to also start to update gps location

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about calling

```
timer.Start();
```

somewhere, when you want the timer to start?

Only after calling the Start() method, the tick event starts firing.